# Running rake db:migrate in Rails fails (table already exists) using mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, dbmigrate

I'm relatively new to developing on rails.

I'm trying to migrate a newly created table using the following command:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

but I constantly get an error that has something to do with the table already existing.  But whenever I try run my rails app I get a Migrations are pending error.

I don't mind deleting the table because I've only just started working on this app so I've deleted my previous migration and I'd run the db:migrate command and there'd be nothing to migrate.  Then I would add a new model again using the following command:

```
$ rails generate model User name:string
```

That then gives me an expected output of:

```
    invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20141129134103_create_users.rb
   identical    app/models/user.rb
      invoke    test_unit
   identical      test/models/user_test.rb
   identical      test/fixtures/users.yml
```

But after that I run:

```
$ rake db:migrate --trace
```

And I get this output:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
== 20141129134103 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'users' already exists: CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `name` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` datetime) ENGINE=InnoDB/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `query'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `block in execute'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `execute'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:228:in `execute'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:205:in `create_table'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:460:in `create_table'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/home/barry/Documents/Programming/Rails Projects/homework/db/migrate/20141129134103_create_users.rb:3:in `change'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:595:in `exec_migration'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1039:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:990:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `block in migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:948:in `each'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:948:in `migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:156:in `invoke_task'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `each'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block in top_level'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:121:in `run_with_threads'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `top_level'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `block in run'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:182:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `run'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'users' already exists: CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `name` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` datetime) ENGINE=InnoDB
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `query'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `block in execute'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `execute'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:228:in `execute'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:205:in `create_table'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:460:in `create_table'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/home/barry/Documents/Programming/Rails Projects/homework/db/migrate/20141129134103_create_users.rb:3:in `change'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:595:in `exec_migration'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1039:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:990:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `block in migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:948:in `each'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:948:in `migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:156:in `invoke_task'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `each'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block in top_level'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:121:in `run_with_threads'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `top_level'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `block in run'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:182:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `run'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Mysql2::Error: Table 'users' already exists
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `query'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `block in execute'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `execute'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:228:in `execute'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:205:in `create_table'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:460:in `create_table'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/home/barry/Documents/Programming/Rails Projects/homework/db/migrate/20141129134103_create_users.rb:3:in `change'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:595:in `exec_migration'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1039:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:990:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `block in migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:948:in `each'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:948:in `migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:156:in `invoke_task'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `each'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block in top_level'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:121:in `run_with_threads'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `top_level'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `block in run'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:182:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `run'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/barry/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

As I said, after running my rails app I get the Migrations are pending error, and I can't seem to understand what's wrong.  Let me know if you need any other files to help diagnose this issue.  The one thing I'm doing different from tutorials is that I'm using mysql for the db instead of sqlite3.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: how about running: rake db:reset command first which drobs your database, and then rake db:migrate More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#resetting-the-database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are deleting the migration, in rails.  However the actual mysql table itself it not being touched (dropped) and then most of your problems are stemming from the fact that the two get out of sync.

Your options generally in this situation are:

```
- `rake db:migrate:down` # To have rails remove the table and keep in sync*

- delete ('drop table users') the table in mysql and then re-run the migrations.

- Use rake db:reset as indicated by jykim to drop the database.
```

- The 'schema_migrations table tracks this stuff and so you can examine this too.

Going forward, don't just delete migrations without considering the actual database tables that exist.  Use the rails down migrations and db reset to keep your mysql db in sync.  At the end of the day it is the schema_migrations table that needs to be correct.

Comment: Thanks for that helpful answer and all the extra information you've provided for going forward :)  Appreciate it!